# Invalid testing environment specified: chrome

Tags: nightwatch.js, automation-testing, nightwatch

[image]

When run the this code got below error-

Invalid testing path

Comment: You need to use `npx nightwatch -e chrome-local` instead of `chrome`

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message states.
You have

> 'default', 'chrome-local'

environments available to you in your configuration file.

You will need to run the command `npx nightwatch -e chrome-local` like the user 'AutomatedTester' said.